# Macbook 3,1: Wireless not enabled on startup after upgrade to 13.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.04, macbook

After having upgraded my Ubuntu from 12.10 to 13.04 the wireless device has stopped working. It simply does not show up in the panel nor in the network settings.

`lspci` gives:

```
$ lspci -nn -d 14e4:
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 03)
```

I have enabled the Broadcom driver under addtional drivers. Also I have run

```
$ sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
```

without error messages... However, when I run

```
$ sudo modprobe b43
```

my wifi shows up.

Now, my questions are:

- What does `modprobe` do?
- How to enable modprobe on startup automatically?
- Is this legit or a workaround that may lead to more trouble in future?

Comment: Before we propose the wrong solution, let's verify the correct driver for your wireless card. Please open a terminal and run: lspci -nn -d 14e4:  Edit your question with the result and we'll proceed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get back to my laptop yesterday. Now, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If b43 is working well, let's make it persistent. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

It may not be installed; that's fine, just proceed:

```
sudo su
echo b43 >> /etc/modules
exit
```

Now does it work as expected on reboot?

Comment: It does! Thanks a lot. I am not so good in Ubuntu, but whenever you have questions on scientific computing I will be happy to help with that.